# How to check exact text in xpath for selenuim webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Is there any way to check for exact text in xpath.

In the below xpath I am getting 2 results.

```
//span[contains(text(),'Vendor')]
```

1. Vendor
2. Company Vendor

Is there any keyword to check for exact text.

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: There is no keyword for it. Just use equal operator.

Comment: The xpath is //span[text()="Vendor"]

Answer (score 3):

If you want your `XPath` to match only the `span` element with text "Company Vendor" then you should use expression with more specific predicate

```
//span[text()="Company Vendor"]
```

Comment: Will it be better to use single quotes? I personally prefer using single quotes when giving attribute values in xpath so I won't have to escape the double quotes in my code (java/c#). Any comments you can provide for this matter?

Comment: It depends on the programming language you use. OP didn't add tag for it, so as `Python` coder I used double quotes as for `Python` and `XPath` there is no difference which type of quotes you use. If you use `Java`, then AFAIK you should use double-quotes for `XPath` and single quotes for inner values as `"//span[text()='Company Vendor']"`

Answer (score 0):

"//div[not(contains(@class, 'hidden'))]/fieldset/legend/..//*[@class='label-text' and contains(text(),"{question}")]/../div//label/span[..//*[text()="{option}"]]/../..//input[@type="radio"]";

thank to @Andersson answer above was my xpath have used text()= and it is now finding me unique value